# C: Solaris SPARC: variable (char) empty after fputs (GCC)

Tags: c, gcc, solaris-10, fputs

I am trying to write a platform independend tool and while compiling a program, which is running under linux, I ran into some problems under solaris.

I use an if-clause to check, if a variable contains the word "OPEN".

```
...
char* oracle_status;
int oracle_status_ok;
oracle_status = get_oracle_status(&oracle_status_ok);
// In the test environment the variable contains "OPEN"
printf("STATUS: %s\n",oracle_status); // "OPEN"
fputs(query_all_dbs,fp);
printf("STATUS: %s\n",oracle_status); // EMPTY
...
```

The query_all_dbs is a initialized in the following way:

```
 char query_all_dbs[] = {
"-- Outputsettings\n"
"set pagesize 0\n"
"set linesize 15000\n"
"set verify off\n"
"set newpage NONE\n"
"set tab off\n"
"set echo off\n"
"set feedback off\n"
"set recsep off\n"
"set long 10000000\n"
"set heading off\n"
"set longc 10000\n"
"set emb on\n"
"-- Requirements\n"
};
```

As said: Linux functional; Solaris Sparc NOT.

Any suggestions?

Regards

Markus

Comment: Did you check if `fp` is valid before calling `fputs` ? Does the "fp" file contain the content of `query_all_dbs` at the end ?

Comment: Hello Michael, yes I checked if fp == NULL and just work with it, if its not. The file contains everything thereafter. It is just the oracle_status, which is empty.

Comment: Try using fprintf instead of fputs and see what happens. But I rather suspect problems in the `get_oracle_status` function. Also try to replace the call to `get_oracle_status` by `oracle_status = malloc(20) ; strcpy(oracle_status, "OPEN") ;` and see what happens. The `get_oracle_status` function might mess things up, and on Linux you get away with it but not on solaris.

Comment: I think you are right. I used a variable twice inside the get_oracle_status-function. Thanks for the hint.